# Variable size for ffmpeg filter

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am creating a bunch of script to easily use ffmpeg.

All my scripts now work, but a lot of value are hardcoded, which make them wanting exact size for the video (854x240, size of my tests videos)

A good example is better than long explanation:

```
ffmpeg -i 0.mp4 -vf "
scale=854/2:-1 [low];
color=c=black@1.0:s=854x240:r=29.97:d=30.0 [bg];
movie=1.mp4, scale=854/2:-1 [high];
[bg][high] overlay=0:0 [bgh];
[bgh][low] overlay=854/2:-1" leftright.mp4
```

It take 0.mp4 and 1.mp4 and put them side by side in the same video. But the dimension value are hardcoded. But it work.

I know I can use iw and ih as "input width" and "input height" for the first scale filter, but when I try to put anything else as dimension for the color background, it just throw me a error:

```
Unable to parse option value "iw:ih" as image size
Unable to parse option value "iw:240" as image size
Unable to parse option value "860*2:240" as image size
```

and I end up to put 1720x240 again, which is really bad.

Is there a way to bypass this, or to put input-dependent value?

Edit:

Starting with video 1.mp4 (854x240) and 2.mp4 (520x520) (example value), put them side by side in out.mp4 (which in this case will have the dimension max(height)x(2xmax(width)), so in this case 854x1040), with black background.

```
  ax
<---->
.____.^
|    ||
|  1 ||
|    ||ay
|    ||
|____|V

    bx
<-------->
.________.^
|   2    ||by
|________|V
```

Will end up as

```
ay>ax
bx>by

    bx        bx
<--------><-------->
xx.____.xxxxxxxxxxxx^
xx|    |xxxxxxxxxxxx|
xx|  1 |xx.________.|
xx|    |xx|    2   ||ay
xx|    |xx|________||
xx|____|xxxxxxxxxxxxV
```

Comment: The [`color`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc) video source filter does not use `iw` and `ih`. Perhaps you can use the [`pad`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) video filter instead. If you included your complete ffmpeg console output and an image representing your desired output I may be able to give you an exact command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard The goal of this script is to, starting from two mp4 video of known (but variables) dimension, put them side by side (one on the left and one on the right, height of the higher video and width = 2x width of higher video), with a black background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the tool has some limitations in the use of these `ih` and `iw` symbols that make them useless. The obvious thing to do is to bypass all that cruft and do the arithmetic in your scripting language, interpolating the results into the command line. For instance, if you're scripting in Bash:

```
x=42
y=53
command "--option=$((2 * x + y))" # pass twice x plus y as value to --option
```

You can run `ffmpeg -i <videofile>` to obtain information about a file, such as size, and parse it out of the tool's output. Use that to set up some shell variables, and calculate any dependent variables you need, then substitute the variables or `$(( ...))` formulas in all the right places in the `ffmpeg` command line that does the transcoding.

Comment: I ll go with that, the script will be use in other languages than bash, so I just have to tell other develloper to replace thoses value in the string command.